# malloc() seg fault in localtime()?

Tags: c, segmentation-fault

Here's ny stack

```
malloc() at 0xb7dfd333  
strdup() at 0xb7e01866  
tzset_internal() at 0xb7e2ef68  
__tz_convert() at 0xb7e2f26a    
localtime() at 0xb7e2d901   
Send_Trace() at my_trace.c:265 0x8053373
```

and here's the offending code ..

```
void Send_Trace(const char const *Trace_Text, ...)
{
   time_t time_now = time(NULL);
   tm = *localtime(&time_now);
```

It is generally working fine, but occassionally throws the seg fault shown above.

Any ideas?

Comment: Multiple threads calling it?

Comment: If you're using Linux, try running your program under valgrind. Likely, memory was corrupted earlier and valgrind might point you at this.

Comment: When you get random seg fault, usually is because you use a local variable inside a function and try to use again (throw a pointer) when the function ends. What is tm?

Comment: Memory corruption?

Comment: If available, did you try to use the reentrant version of `localtime`? `localtime_r()`. I case of you are calling Send_Trace from a signal or something like an ISR.

Answer (score 4):

> Any ideas?

Any crash inside `malloc` or `free` is in 99.999% of cases the result of earlier heap corruption elsewhere.

Examples of heap corruption which could lead to subsequent crash in `malloc`: calling `free` on a non-allocated memory, calling `free` on some pointer twice, overflowing or underflowing a heap-allocated buffer, etc. etc.

The fastest way to find such bugs are: [valgrind](http://valgrind.org) (if available on your platform), or [AddressSanitizer](https://github.com/google/sanitizers/wiki/AddressSanitizer) (implemented in recent versions of Clang and GCC).